# problems to add data in pivot table laravel 5.1

Tags: laravel-5

I hope you are fine.
I have a problem with a pivot table in laravel 5.1
I want it that several products are inserted into this table , which have made ​​relations with two more tables . The problem is that inserts well ids products, but the extra fields such as quantity and price would not add them all , that is , I only adds a value of one product, do not know if I explained well . Of all forms attached photos of models , drivers and user view with the database .
Is there something missing I do? Please if you can help me .
Beforehand thank you very much!!
PD: Sorry my english. I´m from latin america and I don´t speak english very well.

http://fotos.subefotos.com/4e0348b36bf41fc1051873d4778193afo.png
http://s32.postimg.org/w4gp59jqt/foto_2.png

Bill model

```
class Bill extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'bills'; 
    protected $fillable = ['date_at'];  
}


public function products()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Product','bill_product','product_id', 'bill_id','dquantity','dprice')->withTimestamps();
}
```

}

Product Model

```
class Product extends Model
{   
    protected $table = 'products';  
    protected $fillable = ['name', 'price','stock'];    
}
```

public function bills()
   {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Bill','bill_product','bill_id', 'product_id','dquantity','dprice')->withTimestamps();
   }

Controller

```
 public function store(Request $request)
{

    $fac = Bill::create($request->all());
    //Obtener ids de lineas de productos
    $productIds = $request->input('product_id');
    $cant= $request->input('dquantity');
    $prec=$request->input('dprice');


        $fac->products()->attach($productIds , ['dprice' => $prec,'dquantity' => $cant]);

}
```

View

```
                                    <td>
                                        {!!Form::select('product_id[]',$produ,null,['class'=>'form-control'])!!}    
                                    </td>                                   

                                    <td width="20%">


                                        {!!Form::text('dquantity', null,['class'=>'form-control','id'=>'cantidad'])!!}

                                    </td>
```

```
                                        {!!Form::text('dprice', null,['class'=>'form-control', 'id'=>'precio'])!!}


                                    </td>
```

Comment: can't get...explain more clearly about your problem

Comment: Hi.
I have 3 tables
products: id, name,price,stock
bills: id,date_at
bill_product (pivot): id, bill_id,product_id,dquantity,dprice.
When I try to insert more than one product i have the problem like this photo: http://s32.postimg.org/w4gp59jqt/foto_2.png
The IDS of the products it's fine, but the extra fields like dquantity and d price only insert one product i think it's the last one if you see the first photo.
I don't need one value of dquantity and dprice, I need all of them.

Comment: Like this photo: http://fotos.subefotos.com/4e0348b36bf41fc1051873d4778193afo.png

I hope I can explain well